# WCF endpoint: Message.WriteMessage changes the closing tags inside the XML message

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I am using a custom endpoint behavior extension to intercept messages as they are received by my WCF service endpoint, using IDispatchMessageInspector. I retrieve the message content like this:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    MessageBuffer messageBuffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
    Message message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
        {
            message.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to obtain the XML message exactly as it is sent by the client, but the XML that is written to the stream seems to be modified by WCF (or the XmlWriter?). My main problem is that it has modified closing tags: `<id />` becomes `<id></id>` everywhere in the XML message. Is there a way to write the message content as it was received by the endpoint without it being modified (or at least without changing the way the tags are closed?

Comment: But <id/> and <id></id> are the same, why does this matter?

Comment: I know they are the same, but I am required to not modify the body of the message in any way. The body needs to remain exactly as it was sent by the client.

Comment: You're not modifying it - the WCF stack on client and service side is.....

Comment: Alright, is it possible to prevent the WCF stack on the server from modifying the message then? It's not the client.

Comment: I think your customer may need to modify its understanding of the term "without change", so that it matches the XML standard. Are they seriously asking for bit-for-bit identical? No normalization of whitespace or any other standard XML processing? In fact, the server may not still have the "original XML" at all. No doubt the server operates on an in-memory XML Infoset, then serializes it back out to tags and such. Semantics guaranteed to be the same, but may be no way to get text to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem. It was not Message.WriteMessage that was modifiying the XML closing tags, but MessageBuffer.CreateBufferedCopy! It turns out I no longer need to copy the message before I write it, so not calling CreateBufferedCopy before Message.WriteMessage produces the XML with the closing tags unmodified.

Note however that the written XML might still not be exactly as it was received from the client, WCF stills changes some things like carriage returns, etc. I also experimented with custom WCF MessageEncoders like I mentionned in the comments. It gives you complete control over how WCF creates the Message object from the bytes received on the wire.

So if you need to prevent WCF from modifying things in the data that was received or you need to access the raw bytes of the request, you can use custom MessageEncoders. See this sample from Microsoft:

[Custom Message Encoder Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but it might be worth a try.

Idea is that the modification to the xml is being done by the xmlwriter.

You could then get the contents of the message by doing a message.ToString().

**EDIT** Looks like WCF will change the XML on the server or client side if you send it over as xml.

What you could do is to send the xml over as a byte array, that way WCF will not try to change it.

**EDIT 2** The custom message encoder that you mentioned, looks like it both encodes and decodes messages. Would it therefore need to run on the client side as well?

Comment: I already tried ToString(), it does not change the closing tags, but it returns a string with garbage binary characters (it does not seem to be encoded right) and anyway this method cannot be used (from MSDN):

"The body can be read only once, and ToString does not change the message state. Therefore, the ToString method might not be able to access the body and might substitute a placeholder (for example, “…” or three dots) instead of the message body. Therefore, do not use ToString to log messages if the body content of the messages is important."

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to pass the message as a byte array. I do not control the client applications, the clients can use any application they want to call my service and I must accept any WCF message. For this reason my service accepts a generic WCF message and do not enforce any contract. I really need to modify how WCF handles the message. I think this is possible by writing a custom MessageEncoder but I don't know if it's the best solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735115.aspx